# If clicked jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Please help me! I don't have a clue, why my code is not working...
Is there any other way to define a variable inside event handler? Or return it somehow?

```
var $test;
$('#click1').click(function() {
  $test = 1;
});
$('#click2').click(function() {
  $test = 2;
});
$('#click3').click(function() {
  $test = 3;
});

if ($test == 1) {
  $right.fadeOut('2000');
  $('#click1').css({
    "color": "#6B1E1E",
    "font-size": "100%",
    "text-shadow": "0px 0px 2px green"
  });
  $animWebs.animate({
    top: 170,
    left: 800,
    width: 400,
    height: 300,
    backgroundColor: 'white',
    borderRadius: 6
  }, 4000);
  $('#img1').animate({
    opacity: 1
  }, 4000);
  $('#click1').removeClass('click1');
} else if ($test == 2) {


  $('#click2').css({
    "color": "#6B1E1E",
    "font-size": "100%",
    "text-shadow": "0px 0px 2px green"
  });
  $right.remove();
  $simpWebs.animate({
    top: 170,
    left: 300,
    width: 400,
    height: 300,
    backgroundColor: 'white',
    borderRadius: 6
  }, 3000);
  $('#img2').animate({
    opacity: 1
  }, 3000);
  $('#click2').removeClass('click1');
} else if ($test == 3) {

  $('#click3').css({
    "color": "#6B1E1E",
    "font-size": "100%",
    "text-shadow": "0px 0px 2px green"
  });
  $right.remove();
  $contact.animate({
    top: 500,
    left: 500,
    width: 400,
    height: 100,
    backgroundColor: 'white',
    borderRadius: 6
  }, 3000);
  $('#img3').animate({
    opacity: 1
  }, 3000);
  $('#click3').removeClass('click1');
} else {
  $test = null;
};
```

My if else statement works, but it seems that my click event doesn't make any changes to a variable

Comment: You should use delegate event binding `.on()` if html of ``click2`` `click3` is dynamically generated

Comment: Try wrapping `if..else if..else` within a function that is called at `click` events after `$test` is set

Comment: Thank you !!! OMG i forgot about that !!! Yes that helped! I have wrapped it in a function and called it inside a click event handler!!!!

Comment: Also, you can use `switch...case` to make your code cleaner.

Comment: if its a simple variable why use a $ in front? and console,log the test value to see the value

Answer (score 2):

From what I can make out, could be down to sequence of events. See suggested code or re-fracturing of code below.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var test;
    $('#click1').click(function(){
        test = 1;
        evaluateTest(test);
    });
    $('#click2').click(function(){
        test = 2;
        evaluateTest(test);
    });
    $('#click3').click(function(){
        test = 3;
        evaluateTest(test);
    });
    function evaluateTest(testVal){
        alert(testVal);
        // INSERT YOUR IF STATEMENT HERE AND REMOVE ALERT ABOVE
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#click1').click(function(){
     $right.fadeOut('2000');
     $(this).css(/* CSS Stuff */);
  });  
  $('#click2').click(function(){
    /* Your Functionality */
  });
});
```